# How does one choose which preposition in this situation?

Tags: preposition, pronominal-adverb

In conversation with 2 native-speaking Germans, I attempted to translate a passage from I, Robot (Asimov)

> He was adjusting the binocular attachments to his visiplate, and the bloated fingers of the insosuit were clumsy at it.

with:

> Er stellte die binokularen Anlagen an seinen Visibänken ein,
> und **dazu** waren die aufgeblähte Finger des Inso-Anzugs ungeschickt.

and they corrected me with:

> und **dabei** waren die aufgeblähte Finger des Inso-Anzugs ungeschickt.

or

> und **dazu** waren die aufgeblähte Finger des Inso-Anzugs **zu** ungeschickt.

with an altered meaning.

How does one explain the choices of prepositions in these cases? And what about "**daran**"?

Comment: The main thing here is probably that *ungeschickt* is pretty much the wrong (or "ungeschickt" (!) ) choice of word here. You might want to look into *ungeeignet* or *hinderlich*

Comment: The English sentence to which this pertains is: "He was adjusting the binocular attachments to his visiplate, and the bloated fingers of the insosuit were clumsy at it." Neither of the suggested German words, ungeeignet nor hinderlich, to my mind, accurately convey the English meaning.

Comment: At least in German, *fingers of a glove* can't really be "ungeschickt" (they're just rubber or textile and lifeless), while *fingers of a person* can.

Comment: *Zu ungeschickt* would imply, that one doesn't manage the task at all. I can't recognize that in the English original. Also relevant: *Dazu*, *daran* and *dabei* are not prepositions, but *pronomial adverbs*.

Comment: "die aufgeblähte Finger" falls das Schwäbisch oder so sein soll versuchs mal auf area52 um babkes.SE zu machen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Hammer's German Grammar and Usage, 18.2.3c: "bei often indicates attendant circumstances, meaning 'in view of', 'with':

> Bei diesem Gehalt kann ich mir keinen neuen Wagen leisten.

Answer (score 1):

In German, *ungeschickt* can't really be used for inanimate things (I'm not even sure if *clumsy* should be used in English for such things). *Someone* can be *ungeschickt* or even certain parts of his body can maybe be, but *fingers of a glove* can't.

My proposal for a translation would be

> ... aber dafür waren seine Finger im aufgeblähten Iso-Anzug zu ungeschickt

Comment: ...aber dafür war er mit seinen Fingern im aufgeblähten Iso-Anzug zu ungeschickt.

Comment: @planetmaker may work as well, but is farther away from the original

Comment: I would appreciate it if we could focus on the question that I have, which concerns the prepositions to use, and is grammatical. My question is not asking for any help with translating the meaning. I am frequently surprised by how inflexible German's seem to be regarding the creative use of meaning. But that is a topic for another posting, please.

Comment: Those changes in adverbs (not: prepositions) are an attempt to "heal" the *ungeschickt* problem. But they don't heal it. Your conversational partners sensed something was wrong with your sentence but couldn't nail it. Only tofro's solution with the additional *seine Finger* or planetmaker's *er* in it heals the problem, and you are also free in your choice of adverb then.